# array_push - befuddled with Zend test example

Tags: php, array-push, ucfirst, zend-certification

While studying for Zend test, I ran across this code which works, but I cannot figure out why given the two strange props in array_push. strtolower and ucfirst are used where there should be variables.  Have I missed some documentation?

```
<?php
    $str = 'MY STRING';

    $funcs = array();

    array_push($funcs, 'strtolower', 'ucfirst');

    foreach ($funcs as $func) {
        $str = $func($str);
    }

    if ($str == 'My string') {
        echo "Correct";
    }
    else {
        echo "Incorrect";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `array_push — Push one or more elements onto the end of array` What's unclear?

Comment: Keep studying young padawan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PHP supports the concept of variable functions. This means that if a
>   variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a
>   function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and
>   will attempt to execute it. Among other things, this can be used to
>   implement callbacks, function tables, and so forth.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 1):

The fun part happens here:

```
$str = $func($str);
```

This is a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) - the functions listed in the array (via array_push) are being called on the string input.